# minWidth not working on column for material ui X-Grid

Tags: material-ui, response

I'm using Material UI X-Grid component on one of my project, I had added flex on column def to cover the entire screen. But I'm facing issue to make it responsive as I added "minWidth" on column def but its not working for me as It's not forcing column to remain at-least equal to minWidth value.

here is one object for one column

```
  {
      field: toCamel(col.name),
      headerName: renderHeader(col),
      flex: renderCellFlex(col),
      minWidth: 200,
      renderCell: (params: any) => appendTableComponent(col, params, index),
      align: renderAlignement(col),
      type: renderType(col),
      headerAlign: renderAlignement(col),
      sortable: renderIfSortAble(col),
      valueGetter: (params: any) => {
        return (
          params.row.displayColumnsData &&
          params.row.displayColumnsData[col.alias]
        );
      },
      //sortComparator: (v1: any, v2: any) => renderSortCompartor(v1, v2),
    }
```

any one please have a look on it and let me know what I can do to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"minWidth" feature added in new version of material ui X-Grid.

"@material-ui/x-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.35"

I resolved my issue by updating x-grid component.